# How to change editText background color (Android)?

Tags: android

I tried this:

rounded_textfield.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#EEEEEE"/>
    <corners
            android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
            android:topRightRadius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

activity.xml:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchField" android:layout_row="0" android:layout_column="0"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext" android:minHeight="50dp"/>
```

In the editor it's grey, but on the phone it's white.

Comment: try to clean and rebuild your project

Comment: Have you tried changing to a more drastic color, like `#FF0000` to see if it works? Your shape looks OK, but `#EEE` is so close to white that it's hard to make sure it works.

Comment: Try replacing `#EEEEEE` with another color code. Then you will be able to check that if this makes any difference or not.

Comment: Try without the corners and padding

Comment: have you tried it on other phones?

Comment: #EEEEEE is a very light grey. It may appear as white on the phone.

Comment: try it programatically ----`yourEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREY);`
or...

`yourEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"));`

Comment: Try changing the color. I tried your code with a darker color and it's working correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is right, just clean the project. One thing you should remember that the different colors look different in different devices according to their display settings and their display screens.

Comment: Man this shud be posted in comments not as a answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Enter Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

**rounded_corner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dip" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named custom_edit_text.xml and put it in xml folder in your res folder of your project.

Paste the following code there:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ffffff"/>
</shape>
```

Now just refer to this xml in your activty_main.xml file like this:

```
  <EditText

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true
                android:background="@xml/custom_edit_text">

 </EditText>
For custom colors visit [this][1] link.
```

Cheers!