# Relative layout background color occasionally changes automatically on Android pre v21

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some issues with somehow occasionally changed background color of views. That could be any kind of view. The only solution I found is to change background color programmatically.

This is my fragment layout. Here default_theme_color is dark blue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/default_theme_color">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bill_layout"
        layout="@layout/estimated_bill"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/bill_layout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_circle"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/shareButton"
        android:background="@color/default_theme_color"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circular_ticker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/circular_ticker"
            />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/clock_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@color/default_theme_color">

           ...

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what I get. The background color beside share button must be the same as clock bg color

[image]

Comment: Here is a answer, you can find http://stackoverflow.com/a/33756389/5567009.

Comment: No, as you can see in layout xml file I have same color in clock background and whole layout bg.

Comment: why are you setting bgn color again and again....just set it once for root layout and leave the child layout bgn transparent. Also make sure if bgn of all image files is 100% transparent; maybe some image has a tint and causing color change! Also try cleaning the code & reinstalling the app on device.

Comment: I duplicated bg color because I thought it would solve my problem. In origin, it was only in root element. I tried app on devices with api v21 and higher, so everything works fine on them. But on devices with lower api version this bug occurs.

Answer (score 0):

> Create a new **values directory** under resource directory and specify the required styles and colors.
>
> It loads up styles based on the version running on the device

[here](http://developer.android.com/samples/TextSwitcher/res/values-v14/styles.html)

Comment: It has nothing to do with styles. As you can see I duplicate bg color on every ViewGroup element.